# Wavelet Multilevel - Different Mother Wavelets

Tags: python, multi-level, wavelet

I have an important question. I'm using a wavelet multilevel transform using the wavedec (pywt on python), but I need to change the mother wavelet on each level. It's possible to perform it?

```
def filtro_wavelet(x, wavelet, nivel):
    
    #aplicar a transformada wavelet
    coeff = pywt.wavedec(x, wavelet, mode='per',level=nivel)
    
    #cacular sigma

    sigma = (1/0.675) * madev(coeff[-nivel])
    
    #computar o limiar
    limiar = sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(len(x)))
    
    #manter os coficientes maiores que o limiar
    coeff[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, value=limiar, mode='hard', substitute=0) for i in coeff[1:])
    
    #reconstruir o sinal
    return pywt.waverec(coeff, wavelet, mode='per')
```

I need specify different wavelets for each level

Comment: I would think that https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ might be appropriate to ask this, but certainly not StackOverflow, because you have no [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly how multiwavelets work (though I'm not an expert). Maybe have a look at this [paper](https://ictactjournals.in/paper/IJIVP_V3_I4_PAPER_4_616_619.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:**

The short answer is "no": according to [the documentation](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html), `wavedec` only allows the user to specify a single wavelet.

**The detailed answer:**

You can technically decompose your input signal by running `wavedec` multiple times, using multiple input wavelets, but then the questions are:

1. How to reconstruct the original signal using coefficients obtained from two different wavelet decompositions?
2. What sense would that make?

Consider the following snippet:

```
import pywt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
ecg = electrocardiogram()
sym5 = pywt.wavedec(ecg, 'sym5', mode='symmetric', level=None, axis=-1)
sym7 = pywt.wavedec(ecg, 'sym7', mode='symmetric', level=None, axis=-1)
```

The output `sym5` and `sym7` are lists containing the coarse and detailed coefficients. Both lists have the same length, but the arrays that they contain have different shapes: check `sym5[1]` and `sym7[1]`, for instance. So if you mix and match coefficients (`sym5[1] = sym7[1]`) and then try calling `waverec` to run the IDWT (`pywt.waverec(sym5, 'sym5', mode='symmetric', axis=-1)`), it will throw a value error:

> ValueError: coefficient shape mismatch

A way to deal is to run the DWT, zero out some of the coefficients, run the IDWT and then combine both reconstructed signals.

Let us do a quick sanity check. For instance, run:

```
sym5 = pywt.wavedec(ecg, 'sym5', mode='symmetric', level=None, axis=-1)
for i in range(3,14):
    sym5[i]=sym5[i]*0
low_passed = pywt.waverec(sym5, 'sym5', mode='symmetric', axis=-1)
```

and:

```
sym7 = pywt.wavedec(ecg, 'sym7', mode='symmetric', level=None, axis=-1)
for i in range(0,3):
    sym7[i]=sym7[i]*0
high_passed = pywt.waverec(sym7, 'sym7', mode='symmetric', axis=-1)
```

You sure can sum the `low_passed` and `high_passed` filtered data, but the output will be slightly different from the original `ecg` signal: in other words, you will slightly alter your original signal's frequency content.

[image]

The same thing will happen if you run your `filtro_wavelet` function using different wavelets. It may be technically feasible but I am not sure what sense it would make.

Could you please tell us why you plan to use different wavelets and what wavelets you are planning to use?

Comment: Hi @Sheldon. Thank you very much !
The optimal wavelets are choose by EBWS method and this provid me a better filter for my signal.